# Single SQL statement to select row, but only if there is exactly one matching row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following SQL:

```
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*)
FROM Widgets
WHERE WidgetName = 'foo'

IF ( @Count = 1 ) BEGIN
    SELECT @WidgetId = WidgetId
    FROM Widgets
    WHERE WidgetName = 'foo'
END
```

It effectively sets the `@WidgetId` value, but only if there is *exactly* one matching row that satisfies the query. The query above is trivial, but consider the case where the WHERE clause is rather expensive. Or if the WHERE clause is more complicated than a single, complete column. (`WHERE WidgetName LIKE '%foo%'`) Is there a way to do a single query to assign the value to the parameter, but only when exactly one row matches, without repeating the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work and won't require you to do more than one single SELECT statement. **You will have a lot of freedom on changing the query thereafter, should you need to, without breaking anything**.

```
SELECT @WidgetId = WidgetId
    FROM Widgets
    WHERE WidgetName = 'foo'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
BEGIN
    --Here you are certain that there's only one matching row found
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Here zero or more than one records were found
END
```

Comment: <facepalm/> Of course! Thanks! Also, the `SET NOCOUNT OFF` statement is not strictly required; from [Microsoft docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837(v=sql.100).aspx), "The @@ROWCOUNT function is updated even when SET NOCOUNT is ON".

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can use a `HAVING` clause to successfully only set the @WidgetId variable when the `COUNT` is equal to one.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT @WidgetId = MAX(WidgetId)
FROM Widgets
WHERE WidgetName = 'Widget Name'
GROUP BY WidgetName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

In the above case, @WidgetId will be set to the MAX(WidgetId) if there is only a `COUNT` of one record after grouping by WidgetName.

I've created a fiddle that you can look at here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e303/21

Comment: I'd use a group by version myself and was just about to post the same.

Comment: Great idea! I may have made the minimal example in the question a little too minimal. I am looking for a solution that also works when the query is more complicated than complete column values. I have updated the question to reflect this. But this is a great solution in that specialized case.

Comment: The group by approach should still work with more complicated "where" clauses and joins. It's a good method to match exactly a specific amount of rows.

Comment: Yeah but it will require every fields in the WHERE clause to be part of the group. That could make the query hard to read and maintain afterwards. Think about WHERE IN or calls to functions, for example...

Comment: And I think it breaks down when the WHERE clause is not selecting exact values, i.e. `WidgetName LIKE '%foo%'` or `WidgetDtm > @SomeDate`. Unless you made those clauses CASE statements that resolve to exact values on which to group, but then you are pretty much repeating the logic.

Comment: All good points... I had only tried to solve the initial example you posed.  It will break down in more complex scenarios.